# How should I send my Username and Password to Backend in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jersey, jax-rs

Currently I am using this method to send Username and Password to my Backend and check if valid in Database.
Code here:

```
@GET
@Path("/login/{username}/{passWord}")
public Boolean Login(@PathParam("username") String username, @PathParam("passWord") String password) {
    LoginService login = new LoginService();
    boolean response = login.LoginCheck(username, password);
    return response;
}
```

And in LoginService I am using this method to validate::

```
public class LoginService {
    private int count;      
    public LoginService() {}                
    public boolean LoginCheck(String uname, String password) {
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        String hql = "select reg.name,reg.password from Employee as reg where reg.name='" + uname + "' and reg.password='" + password + "'";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {            
            it.next();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total rows: " + count);
        if (count == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }       
}
```

I want to know is there any other safest way to send Username and Password? As in here username and password are reflected in URL.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Never store passwords in plain text!!! Hash (with salt) the password on the client. Send it to the server and check that hash against the stored hash

Comment: Sending the password in plaintext is not a problem if using a *secure connection* (eg. HTTPS) - sending the 'stored hash' from the client is generally less secure because then the hash *becomes* the plaintext password. In the backend, follow the standard rules of password management and storage (with valid hash algorithms, salt, separation of security principles etc.) - this topic has been beaten to death and so I'm voting as Too Broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using *Basic Auth* ([RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#page-5)). A Servlet filter implementing it may look like:

```
package transfer.util;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

import org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter;

import transfer.business.users.entity.Roles;

@WebFilter("/api/*")
public class BasicAuthFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final HttpSession session, final FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // insert cookie erasure here if needed

        dontCache(response);

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (isNotBlank(authHeader)) {
            if (isValid(authHeader)) {
                chain.doFilter(wrapRequest(request, new SimplePrincipal(webHookUser, Roles.ISSUETRACKER)), response);
            } else {
                sendAuthError(response);
            }
        } else {
            sendAuthError(response);
        }
    }

    private void dontCache(final HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    }

    private boolean isValid(final String authHeader) {
        // check credentials and return true or false
    }

    private HttpServletRequest wrapRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final SimplePrincipal principal) {
        final HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
            @Override
            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                return principal;
            }

            @Override
            public String getRemoteUser() {
                return principal.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isUserInRole(final String role) {
                return principal.getRoles().contains(role);
            }
        };
        return wrapper;
    }

    private void sendAuthError(final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"default\"");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

This example utilizes [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) and [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). It does not show the concrete validation query for the user credentials. Please see [Giovanni Lovatos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42062900/1725096) on *Parameterized SQL Queries*. As he also mentions, this is only secure over HTTPS which adds transport encryption and server authentication and optionally client authentication through certificates. The configuration of HTTPS/TLS differs between Java application server implementations.

Answer (score 0):

A safer way to send username and password data to your backend could be a `POST` request, which would prevent having the both the fields in the request URL:

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public boolean login(@FormParam("username") String username,
                     @FormParam("password") String password) {
    LoginService login = new LoginService();
    boolean response = login.LoginCheck(username, password);
    return response;
}
```

Then, if you are using an HTML form to login, you will have something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```

Note that the `POST` request will still have the password in cleartext in its body, so it's mandatory for security to have the service running in a TLS (i.e., over HTTPS).

Least but not last, you should absolutely avoid to build SQL queries with string concatenation, especially when passwords are involved, since this could lead to *SQL Injection*[1]. You should use prepared statements and parameters, which comes pretty easy with Hibernate:

```
String hql = "select reg.name, reg.password from Employee as reg where reg.name = ? and reg.password = ?";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter(1, uname);
query.setParameter(2, password);
```

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Using the POST is cleaner, but not much safer. It only prevent someone in your back to see the parameters, but this won't be hard to find the form paramter in the request. But definitly better to use `PreparedStatement` !

Comment: @AxelH I added a note about having the service run through TLS.